This script will operate only on DataTables.net. Please see https://datatables.net/tn/24 for more details
In my website following error occurs in every page. i didnt change anything in code and this error occurs suddenly
This script will operate only on DataTables.net. Please see https://datatables.net/tn/24 for more details
This error occur in whole site and in console log shows "dataTables.editor.min.js:8 Uncaught See https://datatables.net/tn/24"
When loading site that error popups in every page

Did you try going to https://datatables.net/tn/24 ? What did you find there? Anyway, please include enough of your website in your question for us to be able to reproduce the error. See also: [mre].
